# Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

He implementado en una página un video `<iframe>` de youtube y me sale en `Chrome 56` este aviso:

`[Violation] Long running JavaScript task took xx ms (50ms allowed)  www-embed-player.js`

Hay que preocuparse?

En `FireFox` no me sale ningún aviso. ¿Un bug de Chrome quizás?

Comment: En la consola de chrome yo activo el checkbox hide violations. Ni siquiera google.com cumple con las expectativas de velocidad de chrome

Comment: @amenadiel -  Gracias... no me di cuenta de ese checkbox... :)

Comment: Ayer instalé Chrome Beta 58 y la consola cambió. Ahora tienes un selector de "verbosidad". Si lo pones en `verbose` aparecen esos mensajes de violations y más barusa. Si lo pones en `info` no aparecen **peeero** tampoco aparece la salida de `console.debug`

Comment: @amenadiel - jeje interesante la info... pero aún me pregunto para que sirve toda esas _infos_ en la consola ... tampoco he investigado mucho la verdad ya que muchos (o todos) dicen que no hay que preocuparse en fin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He editado la respuesta con información nueva.

### Es un bug de todos los navegadores que sólo Chrome detecta, por ahora

Al parecer se trata de un bug, reportado en [Chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=662497).

He leído que no es sólo un bug de Chrome, sino de todos los navegadores, pero que el único que lo detecta por ahora es Chrome:

> The underlying problems are there in the other browsers but the
>   browsers just aren't telling you there's a problem.
>
> ---
>
> Los
>   problemas subyacentes están ahí en los otros navegadores, pero los
>   navegadores simplemente no están diciendo que hay un problema.
>   Fuente: [Una de las respuestas a la pregunta: *Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms* de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356270/5587982).

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿Hay que preocuparse?

Según [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42356270/5587982):

*Estos mensajes **son advertencias en lugar de errores** porque realmente no van a causar grandes problemas. Puede causar que las frames se caigan...* y otros problemas, pero no ligados a la seguridad.

**En cuanto a la seguridad no hay que preocuparse**, pues es una advertencia (warning) de que algo no está optimizado en nuestra página. Entonces **sí hay que preocuparse por optimizar nuestro contenido** (ver algunos enlaces al final).

### Posibles soluciones

En [gonodejs](http://gonodejs.com/2017/03/16/node-js-violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms/) dan varias posibles soluciones al problema (en inglés). Aunque considero, personalmente, que no vale la pena intentarlas, ya que lo del mensaje viene resuelto en Chrome 57...

### Ya está resuelto, lo del mensaje

[Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations) todavía en versión beta, oculta estos y otros mensajes de depuración de forma predeterminada. Para mostrarlos hay que hacer clic en la flecha junto a 'Info' y seleccionar 'Verbose'.

[Chrome 57](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html), ya disponible, activa "ocultar violaciones" de forma predeterminada. Para volverlos a activar, debes activar los filtros y desmarcar la casilla "Ocultar violaciones".

### Pero... queda una tarea pendiente

La tarea pendiente es **OPTIMIZAR**.

Aunque ya no veas aparecer el molesto mensaje, es posible que en nuestra aplicación haya un problema de optimización.

¿Qué hacer entonces? Sin duda actualizar a la última versión de Chrome y de vez en cuando activar el modo `Verbose` para ver si hay algo que necesita ser optimizado.

En cuanto a la optimización, puedes encontrar contenido interesante en Chrome Dev Tools, además en español. Te dejo sólo algunos enlaces que he encontrado:

- [Optimización de la ejecución de JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution).
- [Analiza el rendimiento del tiempo de ejecución](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)
- [Reglas y recomendaciones de PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/page-speed-rules-and-recommendations)

La respuesta citada más arriba de Stackoverflow en inglés también proporcionan algunas sugerencias en cuanto a la optimización.

Comment: +1 - Gracias... últimamente estoy también abarrotado de trabajo... al parecer en Chrome 57 por defecto está la casilla `Hide violations` por defecto ya `checked` y [amenadiel](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51796/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms/#comment-103933) dijo que también va cambiar el comportamiento en la versión 58... saludos

Comment: @aldanux He añadido nueva información que podría servirte. Mi conclusión es: en este caso, preocupación en cuanto a la seguridad: ninguna, en cuanto a la optimización: claro que sí. Aunque se pueda ocultar el horrible mensaje, no significa que esté todo resuelto, pues puede subyacer un contenido lento, no optimizado y esto, como es evidente, tiene sus consecuencias. Saludos.

Comment: Perdón por la tardanza y gracias por tu tiempo! Saludos